# Где искать ошибку при встраивании яндекс-карт на сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-карты

Я получил из яндекс конструктора скрипт, вставил его в пустой html файл. Запустил. Карта появилась и работает. Вставляю тот же самый скрипт в html код сайта - карта не отображается. Консоль выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: e.parentNode is null  js:1:1028

Вот текст скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://api-     maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=yRglIwGQGqvcoFfZ5oFjDHll5LSBKD68&width=400&height=400&lang=ru_RU&sourceType=constructor"></script>
```

Comment: e.parentNode - это родительский узел. например, проверьте правильность указания высоты-ширины для родителя, в который вставляется эта карта.

Comment: Наверно это баг, стоит отправить в  Яндекс.  В скрипте на этом месте находится: `e.parentNode.insertBefore(n,e)`, далее есть проверка на `e.parentNode`, но в этом месте почему-то нет.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Могли бы вы скинуть ссылку с картой? Такая ошибка может происходит, если скрипт был удален после добавления на страницу. Скрипт пытается создать карту, но не находит себя в DOM. Тут может помочь или добавление карты с GET-параметром id (поиск себя в документе не происходит; карта сразу будет добавлена в элемент по id). Если совсем ничего не помогает, то можно добавить карту через iframe. Тогда страница никак не будет влиять на работу скрипта.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/211079)

Comment: @Эдуард, ты уверен, что вариант "скрипт удалён из DOM" не является ответом?

Comment: Вообще как раз является